# MongoDB query in Spring data to find map object by key

Tags: json, spring, mongodb

In my Spring project, I want to get some json documents from a MongoDB, by the key of a map.

user.json

```
{
  "client-id": "1",
  "parameters": {
    "prod": {...},
    "test": {...}
    ...
  }
}
```

User.java (Server is a Java object)

```
@org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document(collection = "user")
public class User  {
  @Field("client-id")
  private String clientId;

  @Field("parameters")
  private Map<String, Server> parameters;
  ...
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String>,
    QuerydslPredicateExecutor<User> {
    @Query("{'$and' : [{ 'client-id' : ?0 }, { 'parameters' : { ... } }]}")
    List<User> findByParameterKey(String clientId, String parameterKey);
}
```

In the @Query how to pass a key name dynamically, and fill { 'parameters' : { ... } } with the key name?
For example I want to call the function like this:

```
findByParameterKey("1", "prod");
```

Comment: I see couple of things not correct. (1) There are two parameters, so do specify a `?1` for the second parameter, (2) `$elemMatch` is used with _array_ fields in MongoDB, and your JSON doesn't have an array field! Take some guidance from [Query on Embedded/Nested Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/).

Comment: @prasad_ Thank you for the doc, I modified my question and I wish it's clear now, I want to construct @ Query with the key name of a map.